# How to get the inputbox entered value as component in the parent class reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created InputField and button as separate component and make use of in the two js files incomeFields and Emifields. Then the two Js file as a component called in mail file called HomeLoanEmiCalculator. Then another file success file to calculate based on the input provided. on click of next button the value will be save in one object and we can retreive the entered value inside the success file to calculate the EMI values. I refer the site below https://www.online.citibank.co.in/products-services/loans/pop-up/home-loan-eligibility-calculator.htm
as we have to create in ReactJS. Below code not working properly. Even am using ref i cannot able to access the fieldvalues

```
var React = require('react');
var InputField = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return{
        value: this.props.value || '',
    };
  },
  setValue: function (event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.currentTarget.value
    });
    setDefaultValue =   this.props.fieldValues+"."+this.props.stateId;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div>
                    <div>
                    <input className="inputText" id={this.props.stateId} type="text" 
                    ref={this.props.stateId} onChange={this.props.setValue} defaultValue={this.props.setDefaultValue}/>
                            </div>);
  }

});
module.exports = InputField;

var React = require('react')
var InputField = require('./InputField')
var IncomeFields = React.createClass({
nextStep: function(e) {     
e.preventDefault();     
var data = {            
monthlyIncome : this.refs.monthlyIncome.getDOMNode().value,         
rentalIncome  : this.refs.rentalIncome.getDOMNode().value,          
otherIncome   : this.refs.otherIncome.getDOMNode().value        
}       
this.props.saveValues(data);
        this.props.nextStep();

},
render: function() {   

return (<div>
            <h2>Please enter your income details</h2>
                                    <ul className="inputList">
                                        <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Gross Monthly Income"
                                                stateId="monthlyIncome"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                required="true"
                                                setDefaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.monthlyIncome}
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_rupee.png"/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Rental Income"
                                                stateId="rentalIncome"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                setDefaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.rentalIncome}
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_house.png"/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li className="width25 hlec last">
                                            <InputField name="Other Income"
                                                stateId="otherIncome"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                setDefaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.otherIncome}
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_cashBundle.png"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
        </div>

    )
  }
})

module.exports = IncomeFields

var React = require('react')
var InputField = require('./InputField')
var EmiFields = React.createClass({

    nextStep: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            mortageLoan : this.refs.mortageLoan.getDOMNode().value,
            persoanlLoan  : this.refs.persoanlLoan.getDOMNode().value,
            creditLoan   : this.refs.creditLoan.getDOMNode().value,
            autoLoan : this.refs.autoLoan.getDOMNode().value,
            outstandingCCAmount : this.refs.outstandingCCAmount.getDOMNode().value,
            interestRate : this.refs.interestRate.getDOMNode().value
        }
        this.props.saveValues(data);
        this.props.nextStep();
},
render: function() {   

return (<div>
            <h2>Please enter your income details</h2>
                                    <ul className="inputList">
                                        <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Any other Mortgage Loan"
                                                stateId="mortageLoan"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_house.png"/>
                                </li>
                                <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Personal Loan"
                                                stateId="personalLoan"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_user.png"/>
                                </li>
                                <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Loan on Credit Card"
                                                stateId="creditLoan"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_card.png"/>
                                </li>
                                <li className="width25 hlec last">
                                            <InputField name="Auto Loan"
                                                stateId="autoLoan"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_car.png"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className="inputList part2">
                                <li className="width25 hlec">
                                            <InputField name="Outstanding Amount on Credit Card"
                                                stateId="outstandingCCAmount"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_rupee.png"/>
                                </li>
                                <li className="width25 hlec last">
                                            <InputField name="Auto Loan"
                                                stateId="otherLoan"
                                                metrics= "INR"
                                                imgPath="images/icons/icon_rupee.png"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
        </div>

    )
  }
})

module.exports = EmiFields

var React = require('react');

var EmiCalculations = require('./store/EmiCalculator');

var aboutLoanStyle = {
    width: '235px', 
    marginRight: '10px'
};

var loanAvail = null;
var homeValue = null;
var monthlyEMI = null;

var Success = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
                <div> {this.calculate}
                    <div className="section1 outputSection">
                            <ul className="outputRack">
                                <li className="c2">
                                    <div className="outputLabel">
                                        <strong>Maximum Home Loan available to you</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="outputValue last" id="loanAvail" ref="loanAvail" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.loanAvail}>{EmiCalculations.getLoanAvail(this.props.fieldValues)}</div>
                                </li>
                                <li className="c2 last">
                                    <div className="outputLabel">
                                        <strong>Value of Home you can purchase</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="outputValue last" id="homevalue" ref="homeValue" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.homeValue}>{EmiCalculations.getHomeValue(this.props.fieldValues)}</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className="outputRack rack2">
                                <li className="c2">
                                    <div className="outputLabel">
                                        <strong>Your Monthly EMI</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="outputValue last" id="monthlyEMI" ref="monthlyEMI" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.monthlyEMI}>{EmiCalculations.getMonthlyEMI(this.props.fieldValues)}</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>

    )
  }
})

module.exports = Success

var React = require('react')
var IncomeFields = require('./IncomeFields')
var aboutLoanStyle = {
    width: '235px',
    marginRight: '10px'
};

var Navigation = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
        return {
                  nextCount: 1
        }
    },
    nextStep: function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
         var cnt = ++this.state.nextCount
     this.props.nextStep(cnt);
     this.setState({nextCount: cnt});
     console.log(IncomeFields.props.fieldValues);
    },
    render: function() {
    return (<div className="inputButtonSection">
            <div className="right step1">
                <button className="blueBtn" style={aboutLoanStyle}>KNOW MORE ABOUT HOME LOANS</button>
                {this.props.nextBtnVisibility ? <button key={this.state.showEmiField} className="blueBtn nextBtn" style={this.props.btnStyle} onClick={this.nextStep}>{this.props.nextStepLabel}</button> : null}
                {this.props.resetBtnVisibility ? <button className="greyBtn reset first" onClick={this.resetValues}>RESET</button> : null }
            </div>
              </div>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = Navigation
var React         = require('react')
var IncomeFields = require('./IncomeFields')
var EmiFields  = require('./EmiFields')
var Success       = require('./Success')
var assign        = require('object-assign')
var Navigation = require('./Navigation')

var fieldValues = {
    principalAmount : 100000,
    monthlyIncome: null,
  rentalIncome : null,
  otherIncome  : null,
    mortageLoan : null,
    persoanlLoan : null,
    creditLoan : null,
    autoLoan : null,
    outstandingCCAmount : null,
    otherLoan : null,
    downPayment : null,
    loanTenure : null,
    loanAvail: null,
    homeValue: null,
    monthlyEMI: null
};

var HomeLoanEMICalculator = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
     return {
                 nextStepCount: 1,
                 nextStepLabel: "NEXT",
                 showEmiField: false,
                 showTenureFields: false,
                 showOutput: false,
                 nextBtnVisibility: true,
                 resetBtnVisibility: false,
                 btnStyle : {
                   marginRight: '10px'
                 }
     }
 },
  saveValues: function(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }.bind(this)()
  },
    nextStep: function(count) {
    //this.setState({nextStepCount: count});
        this.showNext(count, true);
  },
    showNext: function(c, bool) {
            if(c===2) {
                this.setState({resetBtnVisibility : bool});
                this.setState({showEmiField: bool});
            } else if(c===3) {
                this.setState({showTenureFields: bool});
                this.setState({nextStepLabel: "CALCULATE"});
                btnStyles = {
                    width: '110px',
                    marginRight: '10px'
                }
                this.setState({btnStyle: btnStyles});
            } else if(c===4) {
                this.setState({showOutput: bool});
                this.setState({nextBtnVisibility: false});
            }
    },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="calculatorWrapper">
                    <IncomeFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                                    nextStep={Navigation.nextStep}
                                                    saveValues={this.saveValues}/>
                    {this.state.showEmiField ? <EmiFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                                    nextStep={Navigation.nextStep}
                                                    saveValues={this.saveValues}/>: null}
                {this.state.showOutput ? <Success fieldValues={fieldValues}/> : null}
                    <Navigation nextBtnVisibility={this.state.nextBtnVisibility} resetBtnVisibility={this.state.resetBtnVisibility} btnStyle={this.state.btnStyle} nextStepLabel={this.state.nextStepLabel} nextStep={this.nextStep}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
module.exports = HomeLoanEMICalculator

var React        = require('react')
var ReactDOM        = require('react-dom')
var HomeLoanEMICalculator = require('./components/HomeLoanEMICalculator')

window.onload = function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <HomeLoanEMICalculator />,
    document.getElementById('emi-calc-form')
  )
}
```

Please help me to do this. pls thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with what you are trying to do:

If you read the documentation on refs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

You will see that you need to assign a ref attribute on the component you want to get the DOM value for.

```
this.refs.monthlyIncome.getDOMNode().value
```

only works if you do something like:

```
<input className="inputText" type="text" ref="monthlyIncome" />
```

One way of tackling this is to have the fields be properties in a state, and based on whether those states are set, trigger your form to move into it's next state. You probabl

The code may resemble something like below.  You still need to implement functions so that onChange will update the state.  You can easily replace input with InputField if input field takes the value via props, and the onChange function comes back up to change the state.

```
 var InputField = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {mortgageLoan: null, principalAmount: null};
  },
  renderFirstForm: function() {
        return (
          <div>Mortgage Loan: <input className="inputText" value={this.state.mortgageLoan} /></div>
        )
      },
      firstFormComplete: function() {
        return (this.state.mortgageLoan != null);
      }
      renderSecondForm: function() {
        return (
      <div>Principal Amount: <input className="inputText" value={this.state.principalAmount} onChange={} /></div>
    )
  }

})
```

Comment: Here am using reusable input text box for different entry of data .so that am using input field as separate component make use of each field section (incomefield, emifield). please help me

Comment: here Input field as separate componet and use it in incomefields and emifields component then bypass the  fieldValues as parameter inside with ref value of each input field that can be used. Onclick of next the value will be saved and move to final page for calculation